# Increase max popup width in a Chrome extension?

Tags: popup, google-chrome-extension, window-resize

I am making a Chrome extension and I need to increase the max width size of the frame window (popup).

If I increase the width of popup.html, then the inner width is increased. I need to increase the size of the popup.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do you mean you are hitting the width limit? You can increase popup width up to 800px, anything over is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the code at the begin of your default popup html file:

```
<head>
 <style>
html {
  height: 200px;  # Set the height and width here. It must be larger
                  # than 25*25 but smaller than 800*600.
  width: 200px;      
}
</style>
</head>
```