# confusion about chrome extensions iframe dimensions and scrolling

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I really hate the way chrome extension development works so I decided to make a regular webapp and use an iframe in my extension. Everything works fine, except for the dimensions of the website and the scrolling on the extension/site.

When developing the site, I knew I was going to use an iframe so I used percentages when formatting the site, for the most part I used `100%` on most divs and textboxes. Anyway, the problem I am facing is that the scroll is extremely wonky on the extension for instance this is a picture of my extension with `400px` height:

[400x400](http://i.gyazo.com/2de5fddb9c09ee53f7c445f1657a3e9c.png). Everything looks fine.

and here is my extension with `800px` height:

[400x800](http://i.gyazo.com/1e8e210f35a5f6de76a4954733bd2b95.png). Scroll appears.

Why is the scroll appearing if I am merely making the extension longer? It doesn't make sense to me.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Expand The Popup Window of My Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983165/how-can-i-expand-the-popup-window-of-my-chrome-extension)

Comment: _"So I really hate the way chrome extension development works"_ Maybe you're approaching it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on the size of the popup window. I don't know the exact dimensions though.

You cannot increase the size of the document past it, scroll will appear.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Looks like ~600px is the max. Thanks.

Comment: I added a link to a better question-answer in comments.