# Google Extension Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I Made A Google Extension That Displays The Date And Every Thing Went Fine But..

[image]

I Want To Put This Wed Dec 2020 in One Line Not Two.

And I Want To Know How To Change The Extension Window Size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure about chrome ext. development, but it seems it works on html css, then you can wrap date in a `p` tag and give it `white-space: nowrap;`

To increase size of the window, you can use height, width on body and html tag, but it has limits.

> Chrome extension popups can have a maximum height of 600px and maximum
> width of 800px.

Source: [How Can I Expand The Popup Window of My Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983165/how-can-i-expand-the-popup-window-of-my-chrome-extension)

```js
date.innerHTML = new Date();
```

```css
p{
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:100px;
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: it worked with `white-space: nowrap;` only